# Why dosen't curl seem to work behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, curl

When using curl behind a proxy,

```
curl -O -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg -v -k -x http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
```

I've got an error as below.  What can I do to solve this?

```
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 8080 (#0)
Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to storage.googleapis.com:443
CONNECT storage.googleapis.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com:443
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Server: squid
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Sun, 13 Jan 2019 16:33:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3149
X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from unknown
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from unknown:8080
Via: 1.0 unknown (squid)
Connection: keep-alive

The requested URL returned error: 403
Connection #0 to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx left intact
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
```

---

I've tried some other things...

1. Without a proxy, it works...

   ```
   curl -O -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg -v -k
   ```
2. When accessing one specific URL with a proxy as below, it works...

   ```
   curl -O -fsSL https://get.docker.com/gpg -v -k -x http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080

   SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
   ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
   Server certificate:
    subject: CN=*.docker.com
    start date: Jul 30 00:00:00 2018 GMT
    expire date: Aug 30 12:00:00 2019 GMT
    issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
    SSL certificate verify ok.
   GET /gpg HTTP/1.0
   Host: get.docker.com
   User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
   Accept: */*

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
   Content-Length: 975
   Connection: close
   Date: Thu, 03 Jan 2019 02:11:40 GMT
   Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 22:59:33 GMT
   x-amz-version-id: JhVckjyzQEkrDSsxn3RySEOXcybUYG7B
   ETag: "5be321089b71e829affab91dd5d5cd3f"
   Server: AmazonS3
   Age: 856
   X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
   Via: 1.1 a8f6d439d4b35a734e48cf0ced363c2d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
   X-Amz-Cf-Id: 07fsnwsaA-9G6q5peUxScboc7l1y5Bov_t5vys0Fp6msPMt9oaXQ2w==
   ```
3. When accessing other URLs with a proxy, it returns the same error.

   ```
   curl -O -fsSL https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png -v -k -x http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
   Connection #0 to host 10.132.2.6 left intact
   curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
   ```
4. Added options like `-v4`, `-v6`, `--http1.0`, or `--http2.0`, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your question is fine. But your screwup in original posting followed by posting a comment as an answer and then posting this a question again makes this all seem just weird. I upvoted this question in good faith and flagged the other question so it can be deleted.

Comment: The way to do it is to merge your accounts; go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles”.